# sort array in day and month in chronological order php

Tags: php, html, mysql

[These are the rows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8XDI.png)
[This is my picture of whats in the rows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKtA6.png)For a project I have to make a calendar. The day and month have to be in chronological order, like name: (DD-MM-YYYY). Now I have already made the table in html and php but I don't know how to sort it.

```
<?php
$connection = new mysqli('localhost','root','','calendar');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM birthdays";

$result = $connection->query($sql);

$birthdayList = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
<title>Verjaardagskalender</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <table>

<?php
    foreach($birthdayList as $birthdays){
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $birthdays['person'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $birthdays['day'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $birthdays['month'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $birthdays['year'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php                                                           
}
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM birthdays ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year, '-', CONCAT(month, '-', date)), '%Y-%m-%d') ASC";`

The better approach is to  use combined columns for date - `YYYY-MM-DD` instead of taking 3 columns separately. For this do the following:

In mysql database, create a column of type DATETIME. Store complete date as `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: can you show me a example where i have to put that line in my code?

Comment: i get the follow error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\calendar\display.php on line 8

Comment: There was some mistake in query. My bad!!!. Please try with the updated answer again.

Comment: it still gives the same error. Maybe there is something wrong in the mysql database. i made a columm in it with the type DATETIME, the columm is called dates.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM birthdays ORDER BY dates ASC";
If this doesn't work, can you share the table snapshot?

Comment: please share some rows from database.

Comment: I shared some photo's. I placed them in the begin of my question. :)

Comment: Ok, your dates field contains all ZERO values. I wanted to say that instead of storing date, month, and year separately in three columns, they can be stored in a single column as 1963-08-05, 1996-05-14 and so on. The format is YYYY-MM-DD(year-month-date)

Comment: is there no way to put it in the table like date-month-year, because for the project i can't use yyyy-mm-dd, i have to use dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: You can change to any Date format in PHP using date() function after getting from database. YYYY-MM-DD is standard format to save date in database.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way making this in SQL to order the data. I mean you can use SQL commands this situation.

You can use ORDER BY;

SELECT * from tableName **ORDER BY** fieldName **ASC/DESC**

(in your situation you should use ASC (Ascending))

```
<?php
$connection = new mysqli('localhost','root','','calendar');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM birthdays ORDER BY birthday_field ASC";

$result = $connection->query($sql);

$birthdayList = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
```

so you did making them ordered :)

Regards

Comment: still get the same error :(

Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\calendar\display.php on line 8

Comment: well. I was mistaken you. So I will give you another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use one field to keep birthday.

Not day, month, year. You keep all together like 1987-12-17 in table

your field type should be DATE;

birthday => DATE

then you can order them what you want by using SQL

```
SELECT * from birtdays ORDER BY birthday ASC
```

well if you get each day, month, year; you have 2 options to do that;

1. using PHP
2. using SQL

**using PHP;**

```
<?php

// 1987-12-17

$birth = explode("-",$birthdays['birthday']);
$day = $birth[2];
$month = $birth[1];
$year = $birth[0];

?>
<td><?php echo $day;?></td>
<td><?php echo $month ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $year ;?></td>
```

**using SQL;**

```
SELECT DAY(birthday) as day, MONTH(birthday) as month, YEAR(birthday) as birthday from birthdays ORDER BY birthday ASC
```

again you can get them by using php;

```
<td><?php echo $birthdays['day'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $birthdays['month'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $birthdays['year'];?></td>
```

Comment: I get the following error: Undefined variable: birthdays

Comment: Did you change your table fields?

Answer (score 0):

I read your images and mocked up a fiddle demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=369bb7f53c2e5f190d5727c6453c892e

I didn't bother to match your column types, but they are of no real consequence for me to show the resultset from my query.  In truth, you really shouldn't be storing the year value as a float -- this just adds more preparation work before displaying to the end user.

The following query will select only the columns that you intend to use and orders the resultset first by month (ascending), and second by day (ascending).  The year value is not factored in.

```
SELECT `person`, `day`, `month`, `year` FROM `birthdays` ORDER BY `month`, `day`
```

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Verjaardagskalender</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (!$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","calendar")) {
    echo "Database Connection Error"; // don't show this publicly: $conn->connect_error;
} elseif (!$result = $conn->query("SELECT `person`, `day`, `month`, `year` FROM `birthdays` ORDER BY `month`, `day`")) {
    echo "Syntax Error"; // don't show this publicly: $conn->error;
} elseif (!$result->num_rows) {
    echo "Possible Logic Error: No Rows";
} else {
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><th>Persoon</th><th>Dag</th><th>Maand</th><th>Jaar</th></tr>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$row['person']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$row['day']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$row['month']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$row['year']}</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```